# How to send a message to the user who logged in through the telegram in website?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to send a message to the user who logged in through the telegram in website?

[Telegram Login for Websites](https://telegram.org/blog/login)

> Telegram bots are a powerful communication tool, but until today they
>   couldn't start a conversation. Even if you wanted them to reach out to
>   you, you had to chat them up first.

and

[Bot API 3.6](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#february-13-2018)

> Added the new field connected_website to Message. The bot will receive a message with this field in a private chat when a user logs in on the bot's connected website using the Login Widget and allows sending messages from your bot.

After login user,my bot can not send message with use user_id,Even the OnMessage event is not fired.

How start a conversation by bot?

Thankful.

Comment: After the user logs in with the widget you will get his user id. I just checked on my bot and private messages to the bot have the chat id set to the user id. So you should be able to use the user id as the chat id an instantiate the chat.

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 5):

You answered your question yourself here :

> Added the new field connected_website to Message. The bot will receive a message with this field in a private chat when a user logs in on the bot's connected website using the Login Widget and allows sending messages from your bot.

More descriptions:
After the user logged in with telegram login widget,you should wait for an update event (assuming you'r using Webhook method for your telegram bot). the update body should be something like this:

```
{
"update_id": 290285,
"message": {
    "message_id": 12,
    "from": {
        "id": 117854,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "language_code": "fa"
    },
    "date": 1549829158,
    "chat": {
        "id": "you need this to start conversation",
        "type": "private",
        "first_name": "user_firstname",
        "last_name": "user_last name"
    },
    "connected_website": "the domain mapped to your bot"
}
```

from the "connected_website" filled you can realize this is a user logged in for the first time and save the chat id to start next conversations in future.
PS : I wonder why there is no documentation about this at telegram or at least I didn't found anything.

Comment: My test shows that only first login from new account will trigger update event with non null `connected_website`. That's the point

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did not receive an update event as a webhook, like Ali Titan described.
But instead chat_id came [to custom `onauth`](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login#receiving-authorization-data) js funcion:

```json
{
    "id': 100102379, 
    "first_name": "Guido", 
    "last_name": "Van Rossum", 
    "username": "guido",
    "auth_date": 1642941713, 
    "hash": "568a5665500a389a754a1c04348ea1c0434d4b507b1920f3ca1ff017a1c04341"
}
```

In this example `id` is exactly chat_id you are looking for.

In other words, if you want to provide it to your backend, you should write something like:

```html
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?15" data-telegram-login="samplebot" data-size="large" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onTelegramAuth(user) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/telegram_widget/login/',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(user),
        });
    }
</script>
```

And then use this `id` to communicate with your user.